# Passing arguments to another shell from tcsh

Tags: bash, unix, tcsh, autojump

I just installed [autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump) but it doesn't seem to be fully compatible with tcsh. In contrast, it works perfectly on bash. However, I want to have it work on my tcsh and thus, I've tried piping my commands to the bash shell like so:

```
% setenv test "cd `echo '. ~/.bashrc; j public_html' | bash`"
```

which worked perfectly since:

```
% echo $test
cd /home/username/public_html
% $test; pwd
/home/username/public_html
```

But I want to bind the following command to alias `j` and its arguments so it will work like the normal autojump program. However, when I attempted to pass the arguments, it does not seem to work, as shown below:

```
% setenv j "cd `echo '. ~/.bashrc; j $1' | bash`"
% $j public_html
cd: Too many arguments.
% echo $j public_html
cd /home/username/.linuxbrew/share/autojump public_html

% alias j "cd `echo '. ~/.bashrc; j \!:1' | bash`"
% j public_html
cd: Too many arguments.
```

But, somehow, if I were to pass arguments like this:

```
% setenv test "echo `echo 'echo {$1,$2}' | bash`"
% $test 2 3
2 3
```

it works just fine. What exactly am I missing?

Btw here's what I'm expecting:

```
% j public_html
% pwd 
/home/username/public_html
```

Comment: What information is sought from `. ~/.bashrc` and bash? Can you set an alias directly? `alias j "cd ~/\!:1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

```sh
% alias jt "bash -c '. ~/.bashrc; j \!:1'"
% alias j 'cd `jt \!:1`'
```

and it worked.

For more info: https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/305